# Filtering FlatList data after every character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList with some data, and I've implemented a filter method which works to a certain extent. The problem that I have is that I have to delete the whole search phrase for the filter to work again, and what I want to do is for the data to update after each character, so for example if I'm looking for 'Bitcoin' and I type in 'Bitf', I want it to display the results again after I delete a character and I have 'Bit' in the SearchBar, as opposed to having to delete the whole phrase and start again.

I also have a small side problem where when I press the SearchBar for the first time, the keyboard dissapears and I have to press it again, and then it works fine.

Here is my filter method:

```
    const searchFilter = text => {
    setSearchTerm(text);
    const newData = data.filter(item => {
      const itemData = item.name.toLowerCase();
      const symbolData = item.symbol.toLowerCase();
      const textData = text.toLowerCase();
      return (
        itemData.indexOf(textData) >= 0 || symbolData.indexOf(textData) >= 0
      );
    });
    setData(newData);

    if (!text) {
      setData(initialData);
      setSearchTerm(text);
    }
  };
```

And here is the whole page if needed:

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Pressable,
  RefreshControl,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import CoinFlatListItem from '../components/CoinFlatlistItem';
import Error from '../components/Error';
import Loading from '../components/Loading';
import {makeRequest} from '../api';
import {SettingsContext} from '../contexts/SettingsContext';
import {SearchBar} from 'react-native-elements';

const Markets = () => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([]);
  const marketCapDesc = initialData
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => a.market_cap_rank - b.market_cap_rank);
  const marketCapAsc = initialData
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => b.market_cap_rank - a.market_cap_rank);
  const priceAsc = initialData
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => a.current_price - b.current_price);
  const priceDesc = initialData
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => b.current_price - a.current_price);
  const percent24Asc = initialData
    .slice()
    .sort(
      (a, b) => a.price_change_percentage_24h - b.price_change_percentage_24h,
    );
  const percent24Desc = initialData
    .slice()
    .sort(
      (a, b) => b.price_change_percentage_24h - a.price_change_percentage_24h,
    );
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('Market High');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const listRef = useRef(null);
  const {currency} = useContext(SettingsContext);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      makeRequest({
        path: `/markets?vs_currency=${currency}&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=${pageNumber}&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h`,
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          setData(json);
          setInitialData(json);
          setError(false);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [refreshing, pageNumber]);

  const searchFilter = text => {
    setSearchTerm(text);
    const newData = data.filter(item => {
      const itemData = item.name.toLowerCase();
      const symbolData = item.symbol.toLowerCase();
      const textData = text.toLowerCase();
      return (
        itemData.indexOf(textData) >= 0 || symbolData.indexOf(textData) >= 0
      );
    });
    setData(newData);

    if (!text) {
      setData(initialData);
      setSearchTerm(text);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({item}) => (
      <CoinFlatListItem
        id={item.id}
        image={item.image}
        name={item.name}
        price={item.current_price}
        rank={item.market_cap_rank}
        percentage={item.price_change_percentage_24h}
        symbol={item.symbol}
      />
    ),
    [],
  );

  const PageButton = ({pageNo}) => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          setPageNumber(pageNo);
          listRef.current.scrollToOffset({offset: 0, animated: true});
        }}>
        <View style={styles.pageButton}>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.pageButtonText,
              {color: pageNo === pageNumber ? 'white' : 'grey'},
            ]}>
            {pageNo}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
    );
  };

  const Header = () => (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.headerName}
        onPress={() => {
          sortBy === 'Market High'
            ? setData(marketCapAsc)
            : setData(marketCapDesc);
          sortBy === 'Market High'
            ? setSortBy('Market Low')
            : setSortBy('Market High');
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Name</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.headerHours}
        onPress={() => {
          sortBy === 'Percent High'
            ? setData(percent24Asc)
            : setData(percent24Desc);
          sortBy === 'Percent High'
            ? setSortBy('Percent Low')
            : setSortBy('Percent High');
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>24h</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.headerPrice}
        onPress={() => {
          sortBy === 'Price High' ? setData(priceAsc) : setData(priceDesc);
          sortBy === 'Price High'
            ? setSortBy('Price Low')
            : setSortBy('Price High');
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Price</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );

  const Footer = () => {
    const myPages = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
      myPages.push(<PageButton key={i} pageNo={i} />);
    }
    return <View style={styles.footer}>{myPages}</View>;
  };

  const Separator = () => <View style={styles.separator} />;

  const Empty = () => (
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>
      Unfortunately, we cannot find the asset that you are looking for.
    </Text>
  );

  const wait = timeout => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
  };

  const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    wait(2000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {loading && !error ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {!error && !loading && (
            <View style={styles.flex1}>
              <SearchBar
                onChangeText={searchFilter}
                placeholder="Search coins"
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                value={searchTerm}
                containerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
              />
              <FlatList
                extraData={searchTerm}
                contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
                ref={listRef}
                data={data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
                ListHeaderComponent={Header}
                ListFooterComponent={Footer}
                ListFooterComponentStyle={{marginTop: 'auto'}}
                ListEmptyComponent={Empty}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={refreshing}
                    onRefresh={onRefresh}
                  />
                }
              />
            </View>
          )}
          {error && <Error />}
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  flex1: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  searchBox: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#102027',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#102027',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerHours: {
    width: '30%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerName: {
    width: '40%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 7,
  },
  headerPrice: {
    width: '30%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerText: {
    color: '#b6bab8',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 35,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  pageButton: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  pageButtonText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    height: 0.5,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#102027',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#102027',
  },
});

export default Markets;
```

Also if you notice any other mistakes or have any pointers or tips, those are certainly welcome as I'm still relatively new to React Native.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.